# How to create a nested json schema with Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

The `INPUT_STREAM` in Kafka was created with ksql statement below:

```
CREATE STREAM INPUT_STREAM (year STRUCT<month STRUCT<day STRUCT<hour INTEGER, minute INTEGER>>>) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'INPUT_TOPIC', VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON');
```

It defines four levels nested json schema with fields `year`, `month` and `day` and `hour` and `minute`, like the one below:

```
{
  "year": {
    "month": {
      "day": {
        "hour": string,
        "minute": string
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I want to create a second `OUTPUT_STREAM` that will read the messages from `INPUT_STREAM` and re-map its field names to some custom ones. I want to grab the `hour` and `minute` values and place them in a nested json below the fields `one` and `two`, like this one below:

```
{
  "one": {
    "two": {
      "hour": string,
      "minute": string
      }
    }
}
```

I go ahead and put together ksql statement to create `OUTPUT_STREAM`

```
CREATE STREAM OUTPUT_STREAM WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='OUTPUT_TOPIC', REPLICAS=3) AS SELECT YEAR->MONTH->DAY->HOUR ONE->TWO->HOUR FROM INPUT_STREAM EMIT CHANGES;
```

The statement fails with an error. Is there a syntax error in this statement? Is it be possible to specify the destination field name like I do here with

`...AS SELECT YEAR->MONTH->DAY->HOUR ONE->TWO->HOUR FROM...` ?

I've tried to use `STRUCT` instead of `ONE->TWO->HOUR`:

```
CREATE STREAM OUTPUT_STREAM WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='OUTPUT_TOPIC', REPLICAS=3) AS SELECT YEAR->MONTH->DAY->HOUR ONE STRUCT<TWO STRUCT<HOUR VARCHAR>> FROM INPUT_STREAM EMIT CHANGES;
```

It errors out too and doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

To create structure in ksqlDB

```sql
SELECT
  STRUCT(
    COLUMN_NEW_NAME_1 := OLD_COLUMN_NAME_1,
    COLUMN_NEW_NAME_2 := OLD_COLUMN_NAME_2
  ) as STRUCT_COLUMN_NAME
FROM OLD_TABLE_OR_STREAM
```

So answer to your question would be, yes you are having syntax error.

```sql
SELECT 
  STRUCT(
    TWO := STRUCT(
      HOUR := YEAR->MONTH->DAY->HOUR,
      MINUTE := YEAR->MONTH->DAY->MINUTE
    )
  ) as ONE
FROM INPUT_STREAM;
```